# vimeo API v3.0 with iOS app: callback URL

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, vimeo-api

I'm using OAuth2Client, and I've successfully allowed a user to login via a UIWebView and grant permission to my OAuth2-enabled Vimeo application.

When the user has given the app permission, the UIWebView just shows the next Vimeo webpage which has the code parameter attached to the URL.

Is this the appropriate way to grant permissions in an iOS app? If so, I don't understand the purpose of the callback URL since you never technically leave the iOS app. So I guess that's my question: is the callback URL required in this case?

I can understand if it is needed if I'm opening Safari (via UIApplication:openURL) to grant access to the Vimeo application I've created. But even in that case the callback URL must not be working properly because Safari never calls my iOS app.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but I know apps can register urls that are opened by your app. You should be able to assign your callback url to be that url you have registered, and get the proper tokens that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was a bug in the version of the API I was using at the time, which has since been rectified. In other words, the API now handles the callback properly.

(I ended up just using Safari as a solution. Meaning, no web view.)

Comment: Could you give more insight in the solution? Do you use a UIWebView or do you let Safari handle the authorization?